# display only the git root directory if it is a git directory in PS1

Tags: command-line, git, bashrc, ps1

I know you can do something like this for the PS1:

```
Corvid @ ~/github/gitdirectory (master) $
```

but, this might be a bit odd: I want to only show the basename of the git directory, no matter where I am in that directory, prefixed with nothing. If I am not in a git directory, I do not want to display anything

For example, if I am home I want it to display:

```
Corvid $
```

If I have entered a git directory, I want it to display:

```
Corvid @ git_project (master)
```

and if I am moving around within that directory, I do not want it to add anything to the path. So if I am at `~/git/git_project/users/authenticate.py` or something, I only want it to display `Corvid @ git_project (master)`

How can this be achieved with PS1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My `PS1`-fu is not that good, but I think this might work:

```
parse_git_branch () {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

parse_git_tag () {
    git describe --tags 2> /dev/null
}

function git_prompt () {
    local OUT=
    local GIT_ROOT=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>/dev/null)

    if [[ -n $GIT_ROOT ]]
    then
        OUT=" @ $(basename '$GIT_ROOT')"
        local GIT_BRANCH="$(parse_git_branch)"
        if [[ "$GIT_BRANCH" == " ((no branch))" ]]
        then
            $GIT_BRANCH="($(parse_git_tag))";
        fi
        OUT="$OUT $GIT_BRANCH"
    fi
    echo $OUT
}

PS1="\u \$(git_prompt) \$ "
```

Effect:

```
bro3886:~/devel$ bash
bro3886  $ cd
bro3886  $ cd devel/nlp/corpora
bro3886 @ nlp (master) $
```

Adapted from [Display Git Branch or Tag Names in your Bash Prompt](http://www.oliverdavies.co.uk/blog/2013/04/display-git-branch-or-tag-names-your-bash-prompt) and [Command Prompt Directory Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147173/command-prompt-directory-styling).